# Select ID is missing

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to get the **Value or Text** of my Select Options but for some reason all the methods I tried won't show me the ID of the Select.
I think that because I'm executing the script before adding the Select in the DOM.
Here is my code:-

JS file:

```
var myimgHTML2="" ;
var myString="";
myString +="<select id='sizesSelect'></select>";
myimgHTML2=myString;
    return myimgHTML2;
```

JS (class) File:

```
$("#myrow").append(myHTML);
```

HTML File:

```
<body>

    <div id="myrow" class="row"> 
        <!-- Row Start -->
        <!-- Row End -->
    </div>

    <table width="100%">
        <tr>
            <td colspan="2" align="center">
               <a class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" id="back_btn" style="width:100px" align="center" onclick="stack_func()" href="#" role="button">Back</a>
            </td>
            <td colspan="2" align="center">
                <a class="btn btn-success btn-lg" id="submit_btn" style="width:200px" align="center" role="button">Select This Theme</a>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>

    </div>

    <script type="text/javascript">


        document.getElementById('back_btn').style.display='none';
        document.getElementById('submit_btn').style.display='none';
        var myPMS = new PMS();

        myPMS.sendToServer('path1_1');

        var uniqueID=[];
        uniqueID.push('path1');

        function callToServer(id)
        {
            var res = id.split("_");
            if (id=="path1")
            {
                document.getElementById('back_btn').style.display='none';
            }
            else if(res[0]=="themeId")
            {
                document.getElementById('submit_btn').style.display='block';
            }
            else 
            {
                document.getElementById('back_btn').style.display='block';
                document.getElementById('submit_btn').style.display='none'; 
            }

            uniqueID.push(id);
            myPMS.sendToServer(id);
        }

     }
    </script>

</body>
```

How I called for my Select ID (JS):

```
var selector = document.getElementById("sizesSelect");
var myvalue = selector[selector.selectedIndex].value;
console.log (myvalue);
```

and tried adding my ID like that with no result.

```
#sizesSelect
```

ALSO, I noted in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1085801/get-selected-value-in-dropdown-list-using-javascript) that they have selectedIndex in the options while that didn't show for me in my Select options.

Comment: "I think that because I'm executing the script before adding the Select in the DOM" - have you tried to do if after?

Comment: Read about document.ready and let us know where in page you have javascript and when it gets executed.

Comment: `myString +="<select id='sizesSelect'></select>";` where is `myString `? It looks wired here.

Comment: @LazarevAlexandr I added the needed part of the HTML file, the way it works I guess difficult, but at the same time I'm getting the Buttons ID with no issue.

Comment: @Adil It works like that 1) Adding the HTML code in JS variable  2) Return the variable to the HTML and print the block.  So I think I need of execute the script after the Returning not during my addition to the code :)

Comment: @LinYuan Sry, added in the code :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

And make sure select tag having a option tag must be selected.

Or

if you wants to get value on change than use on method like this:

```
$(document).on('change', '#sizesSelect', function(){
    var value = $(this).val();
    alert(value);
});
```

Comment: That's great now I can get the value it seems that what I was seeking for.
Thanks a lot.